# ScriptSharp (Script#) and Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, script#

My script sharp actions are getting renamed so they are prefixed with an underscore. Although the code runs just great in the browser, it's annoying to have to remember to add the underscore to use it client side. Is this by design and is there a way to change it?

Here is a sample:
I've reproduced - Knockout JS's tutorial example "Click Counter".

Script Sharp View Model (C# code):

```cs
public sealed class ClickCounterViewModel
{
    public Observable<int> numberOfClicks;

    //Dependent Observable is now called computed but is backward compat.
    public DependentObservable<bool> hasClickedTooManyTimes;

    //WARNING - this get converted to _registerClick Client Side - not sure why.
    Action registerClick;
    Action resetClicks;

    public ClickCounterViewModel()
    {
        numberOfClicks = Knockout.Observable<int>(0);
        registerClick = delegate() {
             this.numberOfClicks.SetValue(this.numberOfClicks.GetValue() + 1); 
        };

        resetClicks = delegate() { this.numberOfClicks.SetValue(0); };

        DependentObservableOptions<bool> options = new DependentObservableOptions<bool>();
        options.Model = this;
        options.GetValueFunction = new Func<bool>(delegate { 
             return this.numberOfClicks.GetValue() >= 3; 
        });

        hasClickedTooManyTimes = Knockout.DependentObservable<bool>(options);
    }
}
```

When this code is converted to javascript the actions get prefixed with underscores. Is this an expected behavior?

Generated Code (javascript) - just showing the generated comments to illustrate the issue:

```js
Knockout2Example2.ClickCounterViewModel = function Knockout2Example2_ClickCounterViewModel() {
/// <field name="numberOfClicks" type="Observable`1">
/// </field>
/// <field name="hasClickedTooManyTimes" type="DependentObservable`1">
/// </field>
/// <field name="_registerClick" type="Function">
/// </field>
/// <field name="_resetClicks" type="Function">
/// </field>
/// This script was generated using Script# v0.7.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooops!

I didn't make my two Actions registerClick and resetClicks public.
Making them public takes care of the issue and they are rendered to js with no underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is a common JavaScript convention meaning "this is private".  Scriptsharp gives non-public members, properties, and methods names beginning with an underscore.  Make your actions public in order to conveniently reference them in external JavaScript.